# No errors just simplifying code

Tags: java

```
if (user.substring(0, 1).equals("1")) 
{
    if(FirstInt.substring(0,1).equals("0"))
        permissionFor0=permissionFor0+"-";
    else if (FirstInt.substring(0,1).equals("1"))
        permissionFor0=permissionFor0+"r";
    if(FirstInt.substring(1,2).equals("0"))
        permissionFor0=permissionFor0+"-";
    else if (FirstInt.substring(1,2).equals("1"))
        permissionFor0=permissionFor0+"w";
    if(FirstInt.substring(2,3).equals("0"))
        permissionFor0=permissionFor0+"-";
    else if (FirstInt.substring(2,3).equals("1"))
        permissionFor0=permissionFor0+"s";
    System.out.print (permissionFor0+" ");
    if(SecondInt.substring(0,1).equals("0"))
        permissionFor1=permissionFor1+"-";
    else if (SecondInt.substring(0,1).equals("1"))
        permissionFor1=permissionFor1+"r";
    if(SecondInt.substring(1,2).equals("0"))
        permissionFor1=permissionFor1+"-";
    else if (SecondInt.substring(1,2).equals("1"))
        permissionFor1=permissionFor1+"w";
    if(SecondInt.substring(2,3).equals("0"))
        permissionFor1=permissionFor1+"-";
    else if (SecondInt.substring(2,3).equals("1"))
        permissionFor1=permissionFor1+"x";
    System.out.print (permissionFor1+" ");
    if(ThirdInt.substring(0,1).equals("0"))
        permissionFor2=permissionFor2+"-";
    else if (ThirdInt.substring(0,1).equals("1"))
        permissionFor2=permissionFor2+"r";
    if(ThirdInt.substring(1,2).equals("0"))
        permissionFor2=permissionFor2+"-";
    else if (ThirdInt.substring(1,2).equals("1"))
        permissionFor2=permissionFor2+"w";
    if(ThirdInt.substring(2,3).equals("0"))
        permissionFor2=permissionFor2+"-\n";
    else if (ThirdInt.substring(2,3).equals("1"))
        permissionFor2=permissionFor2+"x";
    System.out.print (permissionFor2+"\n");
}
```

Can someone help me simplify this code so that it isn't so large. It looks like it's hard coded I know. It is a section of my code that I had to copy and paste four times and it makes the code just look bulky and not very good. I tried to see if I could throw it into some for loops but I didn't come up with anything spectacular.

Comment: Should start with the naming convention.

Comment: Use a loop, and put it in an iteration. Use the index and the index+1 as values, instead of going (0.1),(1.2), ...

Comment: @Stultuske But how do I make it so that the letters will change in the loop?

Comment: @AustinClark why would that logic change?

Comment: This question might be more suitable for the [Code Review Community of Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like:

```
function getPermissions(s, permissions) {
    var i, r = '';
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (s[i] === '0') {
            r += '-';
            continue;
        }
        if (s[i] === '1') {
            r += permissions[i];
        }
    }
    return r;
}

// call
getPermissions('001', 'rws')
```

Maybe it can be written a bit shorter, if the data base would be better presented. For example, if we can skip `'0'` and use only `'1'`:

```
function getPermissions(s, permissions) {
    var i, r = '';
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        r += s[i] === '1' ? permissions[i] : '-';
    }
    return r;
}

// call
getPermissions('111', 'rwx')
```

Or a even a bit shorter:

```js
function getPermissions(s, permissions) {
    return permissions.split('').map(function (a, i) {
        return s[i] === '1' ? a : '-';
    }).join('');
}

// call
document.write(getPermissions('001', 'rwx'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this:

```
    FirstInt.substring(0,1).equals("0")
```

as

```
    FirstInt.charAt(0) == '0'
```

Then you can rewrite

```
    permissionFor0=permissionFor0+"-";
```

as

```
    permissionFor0 += "-";
```

Then you can identify some clear repetition; e.g. you have a block that looks like cut-and-paste for `FirstInt`, `SecondInt` and `ThirdInt`.  You could declare an array of ints like this.

```
    String[] ints = new String[] {FirstInt, SecondInt, ThirdInt};
```

and then use a `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` loop to replace the cut-and-paste repetition.  Or make the loop body a method that you call with `FirstInt`, `SecondInt` and `ThirdInt` as parameters.

And so on.

---

It is not hard to do if you (carefully) do a series of rewrites to your code, each one applying some simple refactoring "transformation".

Answer (score 0):

Like [Stultuske](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156191/no-errors-just-simplifying-code#comment56059207_34156191) already said, you can simply put this in a loop. My recommendation would be to put most of these variables in arrays (or lists, just how it works for you):

```
String[] theInt = new String[]{"", "", ""};
String[] permissionFor = new String[]{"", "", ""};
String[] permissions = new String[]{"r", "w", "x"};
```

And then you can simply use them like this:

```
    if (user.substring(0, 1).equals("1")) {
        for ( int n = 0; n < theInt.length; n++ ) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
                if (theInt[n].substring(i, i + 1).equals("0")) {
                    permissionFor[n] += "-";
                } else if (FirstInt.substring(i, i + 1).equals("1")) {
                    permissionFor[n] += permissions[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println(permissionFor[n] + " ");
        }
    }
```

or you can even use `switch` instead of `if else` for better readability:

```
switch (theInt[n].substring(i, i + 1)) {
    case "0": permissionFor[n] += "-"; break;
    case "1": permissionFor[n] += permissions[i];break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I whould write a convert method like this:

```
public String convert(String iPermission, String mask, char falseCharacter){
    String res = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < iPermission.length(); i++)
            if(iPermission.charAt(i) == '1')
                res += mask.charAt(i);
            else if(iPermission.charAt(i) == '0')
                res += falseCharacter;
    return res;
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```
if(user.substring(0, 1).equals("1"))
{
    permissionFor0 = convert(FirstInt, "rws", '-');
    permissionFor1 = convert(SecondInt, "rwx", '-');
    permissionFor2 = convert(ThirdInt, "rwx", '-');

    System.out.println(permissionFor0 + " "
        + permissionFor1 + " " + permissionFor2);
}
```